# Disable Instagram Video Auto-Play in iMessage

Tags: messages, ios, instagram

My wife just forwarded me an Instagram video in the Messages app, and annoyingly, the video began auto-playing on my phone (though without audio). Every time I go back to that conversation, the video starts up again.

Is there a setting, either in iMessage or in Instagram itself, to disable this auto-play?

Comment: I know you can disable auto-play videos in the Instagram app itself. Open Instagram, go to your profile by tapping on the bottom-right most icon. Now tap on the settings icon (the cog wheel) on top-right. You see the ‘Auto-play Videos’ option? Turn that thing off. That’s it.

Comment: @DrZoo - which version of Instagram do you have installed (Settings -> Open Source Libraries) ? Mine shows me 9.6.0, and I don't have a "Auto-play Videos" option.